# Strange Problem with File.Move command

Tags: c#, .net

I have encountered a strange problem when using the File.Move command. The Programm actually moves and renames the file, but then throws me an exception that the sourcefile is not found; - what is expected because the File was moved.

The Program works fine if i catch the Exception but i'm wondering why i get these exception.

My Code:

```
  foreach (string str in CPM.prot.FKFinishedBad) 
  {   
        try  
        {  
          string dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ResultDir"] + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + "_Bearbeitete Protokolle";  
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))  
        {  
          Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);  
        }  
          File.Move(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ResultDir"] + "\\" +  str + "_" + CPM.LastJob + ".txt", dir + "\\" + "\\" + str + "_" + CPM.LastJob + "_Nachproduziert" + ".txt");  
        }  
        catch (Exception e)  
        {  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Are there duplicates in `FKFinishedBad`?

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have explorer open to watch the files you're moving. I once spent an entire day chasing a retarded exception like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure all of your files exist?
It might happen that one of them is missing (which explains the exception), while the others are processed correctly. you can also check them before the move with File.Exists.

Also, be careful when using empty catch blocks, they can cause a lot of headaches when debugging.

Comment: agree, the best way is to always use File.Exists before doing a File.Move  and this will assure it wont throw any exception.

Comment: I really dont understand this but it is the Solution. BUT All Files existed already before so if anybody could explain me this i would be very thankful. BTW i'm so sure that the Files existed before because i let the user chose if the Files should be deleted ore moved and deleting with exact the same name works fine

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that each item in CPM.prot.FKFinishedBad is unique - that may be a cause of the phenomenon.

Also, I'd recommend to refactor the code: the directory lines don't need to be repeated and should be outside of the loop.

And please learn to use String.Format and Path.Combine.

Comment: No every file is unique and exists. As i tried to explain, the moving of the files works fine but after that i got the exception because of the then not anymore existing source file what is obvious because it was moved, at least this is my understanding of the Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to suspend a thread for a half a second (or less) here:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))  
{  
  Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);  
  //suspend thread for 0.5 sec
}
```

This is probably related to fact that  you create a directory and immediately move a file. So suspend a thread to let "breath" to system.

Comment: Tried it and this is not the Reason but Thanks for the fast Answer

Answer (score 0):

I have just been experiencing this problem, it took me a while to realise that there is a `FileInfo.MoveTo` command which appears to do the same thing.

However it doesn't throw an exception, and works.

It is a bit dodgy if there are two ways to do one thing and only one of them works.